# How to use namespace in django + Problems after this

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I looked at the official Django documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) and the error code and wrote the following. How can I write namespaces to work?

views.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('math/', include('math_note.urls', namespace='math-note'))
]
```

templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'home:math-note' %}">math note</a>
```

Error when running runserver:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.`

Question:
How can I use the namespace function?

Second question:

Thank you! Well connected via
`<a href="{% url 'music:home-page' %}">`(to app_name = music)

But when I call the form from the music app and load the url to generate, I get an error. The other URLs didn't have any issues, only this one.

`Reverse for 'home-page' not found. 'home-page' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

#music/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'music'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.music_home_page, name='home-page'),
    path('new/', views.new_song, name='new'),
    path('music_player/<int:id>/', views.music_player, name='music-player'),
]
```

Question:
I solved the previous problem and got the following problem. What is the cause and solution of this?

Comment: You need to specify an `app_name` in `math_note.urls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `namespace` kwarg that `include` accepts is an *instance namespace* i.e. an instance of an application namespace, you cannot have instance namespaces without having an *application namespace* which as the error specifies you do by specifying `app_name` in the included module or by passing a 2-tuple containing the patterns and application namespace to `include`.

Hence you need to modify **`math_note.urls`** and add an `app_name` variable to it:

```
app_name = 'math_note'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

Keep your other urls (likely in `home.urls`?) as it is:

```
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('math/', include('math_note.urls', namespace='math-note'))
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Well connected via <a href="{% url 'music:home-page' %}">. (to app_name = music) But when I call the form from the music app and load the url to generate, I get an error. The other URLs didn't have any issues, only this one. error: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: No reversal found for 'home page'. 'Homepage' is not a valid view function or pattern name Question: I solved the previous problem and got the following problem. What is the cause and solution of this?_____________________________________________ Is my question too long? Post a new question?

Comment: @cuber_june show your `urls.py` file for the app where you have this pattern named `home-page`

Comment: #music/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
# from .views import CreatePostView

app_name = 'music'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.music_home_page, name='home-page'),
    path('new/', views.new_song, name='new'),
    path('music_player/<int:id>/', views.music_player, name='music-player'),
]
```

Comment: @cuber_june not in the comments, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67998265/edit) your question.

Comment: @cuber_june do you include this apps url patterns elsewhere?

Comment: This does not include app URL patterns anywhere else.

Comment: I don't know if this will help. What this app does is receive the video link and video title from the user, and use youtube-dl to download and play the video.

Comment: Oh I wrote down all the URLs in the navbar. @Abdul Aziz Barkat

Answer (score 0):

just remove namespace from the path.
including a url does not require to have namespace. having your namespace on your math-notes is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`app_name` in application `url` will work as `namespace`. just remove `namespace` from `include` in root project directory.

your `urlpatterns` should look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('math/', include('math_note.urls'))
]
```

and define `app_name='home'` in your application `urls`.
something like:

```
`app_name='home'`

urlpatterns = [
        path('list/', <your view>, name='app-list'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

second question answer.

I have set the navbar so I can't see the exact error code content. When I deleted the navbar, I saw the exact error content, and the cause of the error was the return link.

Answer (score -1):

**views.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('math/', include('math_note.urls', name='math-note'))
]
```

Use `name` instead of `namespace`